# Kafka: isolation level implications

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a use case where I need 100% reliability, idempotency (no duplicate messages) as well as order-preservation in my Kafka partitions.  I'm trying to set up a proof of concept using the transactional API to achieve this.  There is a setting called 'isolation.level' that I'm struggling to understand.

In this [article](https://hevodata.com/blog/kafka-exactly-once/), they talk about the difference between the two options

> There are now two new isolation levels in Kafka consumer:
>
> read_committed: Read both kind of messages that are not part of a
> transaction and that are, after the transaction is committed.
> Read_committed consumer uses end offset of a partition, instead of
> client-side buffering. This offset is the first message in the
> partition belonging to an open transaction. It is also known as “Last
> Stable Offset” (LSO). A read_committed consumer will only read up till
> the LSO and filter out any transactional messages which have been
> aborted.
>
> read_uncommitted: Read all messages in offset order without
> waiting for transactions to be committed. This option is similar to
> the current semantics of a Kafka consumer.

The performance implication here is obvious but I'm honestly struggling to read between the lines and understand the functional implications/risk of each choice.  It seems like `read_committed` is 'safer' but I want to understand why.

Comment: Edited to make it clear that I *am* using the transactional api.

Comment: But probably we have to mention that transactions are connected with Kafka Streams. So transactions are used in stream processing especially where aggregations and/or joins are included.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, the `isolation.level` setting only has an impact on the consumer if the topics it's consuming from contains records written using a transactional producer.

If so, if it's set to `read_uncommitted`, the consumer will simply read everything including aborted transactions. That is the default.

When set to `read_committed`, the consumer will only be able to read records from committed transactions (in addition to records not part of transactions). It also means that in order to keep ordering, if a transaction is in-flight the consumer will not be able to consume records that are part of that transation. Basically the broker will only allow the consumer to read up to the Last Stable Offset (LSO). When the transation is committed (or aborted), the broker will update the LSO and the consumer will receive the new records.

If you don't tolerate duplicates or records from aborted transactions, then you should use `read_committed`. As you hinted this creates a small delay in consuming as records are only visible once transactions are committed. The impact mostly depends on the sizes of your transactions, ie how often you commit.

Comment: If you were to say publish a million messages in a transaction but also have normal non-transactional messages from users at the same time, there would be a large lag time when that bulk send happens right? From what I read the kafka cluster wont abort your transaction for 15 minutes by default (seems like it could really stall all consumers of that topic for a long time). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

> if so, if it's set to `read_uncommitted`, the consumer will simply read everything including aborted transactions. That is the default.

To clarify things a bit for readers: this is the default only in the [Java Kafka client](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3.2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.java#L320). It was done to not change the semantics when transactions were introduced back in the day.

It's the **opposite** in librdkafka which sets the `isolation.level` configuration to `read_committed` by default. As a result, all libraries built on top of librdkafka will consume only committed messages by default: [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python), [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet), [rdkafka-ruby](https://github.com/appsignal/rdkafka-ruby).

KafkaJS consumers also uses [read committed by default](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming) (`readUncommitted` set to `false`).

Comment: Is it possible to fetch Last Stable Offset (LSO) using any function in librdkafka?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using transactions in your producer, the isolation level does not matter. If you are, then you must use `read_committed` if you want the consumers to honor the transactional nature. Here are some additional references:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/
https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Jqy_GjUGtdXJK94XGsEIK7CP1SnQGdp2eF0wSw9ra8/edit