# Kafka Commit: Producer vs Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

It's been a couple of months that I am learning Kafka, and
I keep seeing the word "**commit**" come up in both producer as well as consumer contexts. It was confusing to me for a long time, but I think I have a better understanding now.

Would be great if someone could validate my understanding, or correct me if I am wrong/missing something in my below understanding:

#### `commit` in Producer:

Commit comes up in a producer context only when we are dealing with transactions. Here a commit means that a transactional producer has been able to successfully write a message to a partition in a topic.

#### `commit` in Consumer:

Kafka does not itself automatically track which consumer has read which message. A consumer needs to notify the broker that it has read a particular message in a topic. This acknowledgment process, by which a consumer notifies which message/partition in a topic it has read successfully (so that other consumers don't re-read that again) is known a "commit".

From the book [Kafka: The definitive guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html):

> How does a consumer commit an offset? It produces a message to Kafka,
> to a special __consumer_offsets topic, with the committed offset for
> each partition

*Also*, *another* area where the word "commit" comes up in a Consumer setting is the "**isolation.level**" of a consumer, ie `isolation.level=read_committed`. This is however only in a transactional setting. When we are using a Transactional Producer, this `isolation.level` of the consumer will specify if it will read messages after they are "committed" by the producer or not. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048562/2715083)

Again, would be great if someone could validate my understanding.

Comment: This is correct. Unclear what more you want as an answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer  i wanted to know what i have assimilated is correct or not.

Comment: Seems correct. Producer commits are only because database transactions use the same terminology. Its not really useful to say "commit" itself. "Offset commit" is the more useful term for consumers

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, a Producer commit does not only mean that a transactional producer has been able to successfully write records to a topic, but it also means that the consumer involved in the transaction (in other words, in the atomic read-process-write cycle) has also been able to successfully consume records from a topic.

Before calling `producer.commitTransaction()`, one should call `producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, String consumerGroupId)` so that the broker knows which records were consumed by the consumer during an atomic read-process-write cycle.

The following code shows a common processing pattern (read-process-write loop) when dealing with transactions :

```
while (true) {
  ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(timeout);
  producer.beginTransaction();
  for (ConsumerRecord record : records)
    producer.send(producerRecord(“outputTopic”, record));
  producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(currentOffsets(consumer), group);  
  producer.commitTransaction();
}
```

In short, in a transactional context, it is also the duty of the producer to "commit for the consumer".

More information about transactions can be found in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)